# ZTE MF180 - BSNL - 3G Datacard USB Modem not working in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, modem, 3g

I'm entirely new to Ubuntu and hence do not have much knowledge about it...
I recently installed **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** version alongside with Windows 7 since i wanted dual booting option.

Here's my problem... The **ZTE MF180 3G Datacard USB Modem (Service provider - BSNL)** is working fine in Windows 7 without any problems but it is **NOT working in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.**

To add to this i do not have acces to any wired network for internet...

I want to get rid of Windows so as to use only Ubuntu but without internet what good would it be right..?

As i mentioned earlier i'm new to this OS (i like Ubuntu... it is much better than Windows) and I'm in desperate need of help...

It would be great if anybody could suggest me clearly how to make my 3G Datacard work...

Thanks in advance...

Ok here is the output of   lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 19d2:0154 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:62c0 Microdia Sonix USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Bluetooth 2.0 Interface [Broadcom BCM2045]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my question was how to connect to internet using my 3g datacard which is not working properly

Comment: Urgency is relative, and contributions to this site are on a volunteer bases. Please keep that in mind.

Comment: Define `not working`. are you seeing the device as storage device? Have you clicked on network manager & there is no `Create New mobile broadband` menu after a minute? If the indicator is there, is it always red or after sometime it turns to greee. Include `lsusb` (execute the command in terminal) result in your question when the device is plugged in. The windows software provided with the application won't work in linux.

Comment: Not working in the sense the software supplied along with the datacard has installed in Ubuntu but when i plug in the datacard the software still says device not found...

Comment: You don't need the software. Ubuntu generally detects most of the modem & provide "create new mobile broadband" option. Check network applet on top right. Or provide the output `lsusb`

Comment: Right... i will try it as soon as possible... Cause i need to switch operating systems to try this...

Comment: A long time you posted this, but did you solve this @HarishDR ?

Answer (score 1):

1.first install according to the setup list

2.next insert the modem before switch on the system

3.Switch on the system

4.then open bsnl modem manager and u can see a cd-rom type icon on the sidebar

5.just open cd rom

6.after that close bsnl modem manager

7.unmount cd-rom

8.again u can open bsnl modem manager and then u can see your modem is recognized just u have to click for connect until wait for sometime for network searching.

Happy browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the internet and run the below command on terminal(ctrl+alt+t),

```
sudo apt-get install udev-discover
```

After installation completed,restart your pc and it works.

Comment: did you have ZTE driver files for linux?

Comment: The data card itself contained the install files for three operating systems namely Linux, Mac OS and Windows... I installed it for windows and in ubuntu but the "datacard is not detected" message pops up...

Comment: did you install the ZTE linux drivers?

Comment: yes i installed the sofwares... but it is still the same...

Comment: restart you pc,Login into ubuntu,click on network icon on the top panel,select edit connections,click on ADD,choose connection type as mobile broadband and then click create option.Your zte modem will be detected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jockey` to search for available drivers. For this to work you need to establish an internet connection *without* your 3G card. Using a wired network will most likely work. Once you are connected run:

```
sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk
jockey-gtk
```

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have access to any wired network... i'm only able to use usb-modem 3g internet on windows but not on ubuntu... :-(